# access violation when running the app in debuging mode

Tags: c, mips, access-violation

im writing a program to run the mips assembly codes using just C . actually a simple virtual machine. but there is problem that really gets me , when i run the code in virsual studio in release mode it works great , but when i use the the debug mode it will run this loop ( with no change ) for 12 time but on the 13'th loop it will raise the access violation . i've debuged the code many times but the problem will occur after the `strcpy` and i couldn't figure out why .

nothing happening in the other functions the problem occurs in this loop (dumped the memory).
i'd appreciate any help :)

```
while ( text_head != NULL)
    {
        if ( text_head->line != NULL )
        {
            strcpy(line_ptr, text_head->line);   // the problem occures here on the 13th loop
            while ( isspace( line_ptr[line_index] ) )
                line_index++;
        }
        else
        {
            line_ptr = NULL;
            line_index = 0;
        }
        if ( line_ptr && isInstruction(&line_ptr) )
        {
            text_head = text_head->next;
            line_index = 0;
            continue;
        }
        else if(!text_head->next)
        {
            text_head = text_head->next;
            line_ptr = 0;
        }
    }
```

and here is the definition of line_ptr and text_head :
definition of STRING_MAX is 509

```
char *line_ptr = (char *) malloc ( STRING_MAX * sizeof(char) );

struct text
{
    char *line;        //memory will be allocated beforehand : text_head->line = (char *) malloc ( STRING_MAX * sizeof(char) );
    char *label;
    char *args[3];
    struct text *adress;
    int isMain;
    struct text *next;
};
struct text *text_first;
struct text *text_head;
```

Comment: If the problem occurs in your debug build, but not your release build, then that should tell you that it's related to the debug compilation (assuming you changed no other code). Have you tried using valgrind or a debugger to help find any null or dangling pointers?

Comment: yes according to valgrind after the strcpy the text_first will become corrupted  for no reason . i dont even pass that to strcpy !. the other problem is that when i run it on the os that i've wrote it will be the same as i run it in debug mode .

Comment: You have to show the rest of the code. For example we need to know how `line_ptr` is defined and what `text_head->line` contains. `strcpy` is an unbounded copy so that could easily overflow `line_ptr` and cause memory corruption. But there is no way we can tell that from the code snippet you have provided.

Comment: i've added the definitions in the post above .